# Does Visual Studio 2022 have an android emulator that has a Barometer sensor

Tags: android-emulator, maui, visual-studio-2022, maui-community-toolkit, ms-android-emulator

Does anybody know if the built-in Android emulator has an emulated device that has a barometric sensor?

Comment: The Android tooling available with VS is all provided by Google, not Microsoft.  AFAIK there is no barometer available in the emulator

Comment: Thanks, @Jason.  That is what I suspected.  This explains why IsSupported found in Microsoft.Maui.Essentials returns false but other methods like Start, Stop and the ReadingChanged event handler still function and reads the virtual sensor data from the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android emulator can't simulate any sensors. Also as Jason said, the Android tooling available with VS is all provided by Google, not Microsoft. And there is no barometer available in the emulator.

For more info about sensor for emulator, you can see this case: [Pressure sensor not getting any values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245827/pressure-sensor-not-getting-any-values).